# no free lunch theorem version 2

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, algorithms

Let data-generating function $f$ be fixed, $D = \{(x_1,y_1),...,(x_N,y_N)\}$, $A$ is set of all possible deterministic learning algorithms and $h:X\rightarrow Y$ is a classifier trained by the algorithm $ a\in A $(meaning algorithm $a_D$ outputs a classifier $h$ ). $L(f(x),y)$  is 1/0-loss function.  Then i want to show that $\frac{1}{|A|}\sum_{a \in A}E[L(f(q),a_D(q))] = \frac{1}{2}$ where $q$ is a test point such that $x_i \neq q$ for all $i$.

My solution is based on my answer here [No free lunch theorem proof](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/571804/no-free-lunch-theorem-proof/572012#572012), here we assume that algorithms $A$ are uniformly distributed and then sum over $\sum_{a \in A}a_D(q)$ instead of $\sum_{f \in F}f(q)$ and notice that $\sum_{a \in A}a_D(q) = 0$. So my question: does set of all possible deterministic learning algorithms output all possible classifiers for a fixed dataset? Can we write $\{a_D \in A\} = \{h \in H\}$ where $H$ is set of all allowed classifiers?